# In Nodejs when using the q (promises) module, what is the value returned by then()?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am not asking about the fulfillment value of the promise.

Here I am asking about the return value of the `then()` function.  The specific thing I am concerned about is building lists of promises based on conditions, such as:

```
function operationThatReturnsPromise() {

  var p = q.resolve({ prop1 : value1 })
         .then(function(ctx) {.... return ctx;});

  if (condition1) { 
   // which usage is required or preferred?

   // 1.  p = p.then() ? 
   p = p.then(function(ctx) { ..... return ctx; } );

   // 2. p.then() ? 
   p.then(function(ctx) {... return ctx; });

  } 

  return p;
}
```

Are they equivalent? 
The [doc at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise) states

> A new promise is returned, whose state evolves depending on this promise and the provided callback functions.

[image: Mozilla doc snip]

This seems to indicate the former (option 1) is preferred. Any guidance?

Comment: I see your background is in .NET , think of `.then` as Task's `.ContinueWith`, and you return a task eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use option 1.

Promises are immutable; `.then()` returns a new promise with the (eventual) result of the callback.

If you ignore its return value, you will never wait for the operation to finish, and, worse any failures will be silently swallowed.

Comment: Worth mentioning that good promise libraries like Bluebird or native promises in firefox do not silently swallow exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the test, option 2 would not work. If you want a promise which resolve with `ctx`, you have to return the return value of `then(function(ctx) {... return ctx; })`. With option 2, this return value is lost forever.

By the way, please guys check the benchmarks of Q, and realize you should probably use bluebird, which is the only promise library I know which has really good performances.

Comment: A lot of promise library developers care about performance. Petka just understands it better than most of the other ones.

Comment: Yep. Maybe this was a little exaggerated.